# How do I calculate the week ending date based on a given date?

Tags: cognito-forms

Week ends on Sunday.  So today, Friday, has week ending date `DateTime.Today.AddDays(2)`, correct?

And in general, if I calculate the number of days from the given date until the week ending date and assign it to `DaysToWeekEnding` (number value), then

`DateTime.Today.AddDays(DaysToWeekEnding)`  , right?

Well I keep getting an error when trying to set the default value of a date field to the above.  "No applicable method 'adddays' exists in type 'DateTime'.   But if I replace DaysToWeekEnding with a literal number (e.g. 2), then the form builder accepts it as valid.

Please help me out of this loop, or let me know of another way to obtain a week ending date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you specifically need to convert that number (DaysToWeekEnding) into an integer. So your calculation should look like this:

```
=DateTime.Today.AddDays(Int32.Parse(DaysToWeekEnding))
```

I hope this helps to get you out of that loop.

Comment: That did it, Jennifer.  Thank you!